# Script to redo a rails migration easily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I need to redo a migration occasionally. The workflow is usually something like this:

1. `find` or `ls | grep` the migration using some keyword
2. copy the timestamp
3. paste the timestamp in `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=123`

As I hate repetitive work, I wrote a small bash script that allows running a migration using only a partial name. If there are many matches, it lists them all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

err() {
  echo "redo: error: $1"
  echo "redo: usage: redo <migration_name>"
  exit 1
}

[[ -d ./db/migrate ]] || err "dir db/migrate not found"

migrations=$(find './db/migrate' -name '*.rb' | grep "$1" | sed 's#^\./db/migrate/##')
declare -A times
for m in $migrations; do
  time=$(echo "$m" | sed 's#\([0-9]*\)_.*.rb#\1#')
  name=$(echo "$m" | sed 's#[0-9]*_\(.*\)\.rb#\1#')
  times["$name"]="$time"
done

if [[ ${#times[@]} == 1 ]]; then
  name="${!times[@]}"
  ver="${times[$name]}"
  echo "redo: executing \`bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=$ver\`"
  bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION="$ver"
  exit 0
fi

echo -e "redo: be more specific, candidates are:\n"
for k in "${!times[@]}"; do
  echo "$k : ${times[$k]}"
done
exit 1
```

I'd love to get feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Error and initial check

I recommend to substitute `$1` with `$@`, so that if you ever forget to quote it will still print the complete message.

```
err ()
{
  echo "redo: error: $@"
  echo "redo: usage: redo <migration_name>"
  exit 1
}
```

I am not sure why you put the usage in that function, since if there is no database, this does not help anyone.

```
[[ -d ./db/migrate ]] || err "dir db/migrate not found"
```

You also may want to check if you have too few/many arguments.

```
[[ -z $1 ]] && err No argument!
[[ $# -gt 1 ]] && err Two many arguments!
```

#### Finding the migrations

I recommend not using `sed` to truncate your pathnames. I also think it is completely superfluous since your trapping a few things later on and can simply ignore the prefix. You also do not need to use `grep`, `find` should be able to do that on his own. Hence instead of

```
migrations=$(find './db/migrate' -name '*.rb' | grep "$1" | sed 's#^\./db/migrate/##')
```

simply use

```
migrations=$(find './db/migrate' -name "*$1*.rb")
```

At this point I would check if it actually found anything, too.

```
[[ -z $migrations ]] && err I don't know what you are talking about.
```

*Note that I omitted the quotes to make the point raised above.*

#### Creating the array

I recommend not using `times` as a variable name, because there is a built-in bash command of the same name.
You can use avoid that `echo |sed` construct by using the build-in regular expressions comparison operator `=~`.

Since I don't know the exact form how the migrations are written, I can only assume that a migration comes in the form `./db/migrate/YYYYMMDDHHmmSS_name.rb`. Where the timestamp is obviously just numbers, but name can be anything.

```
declare -A migration_times
for select_migration in $migrations; do
    pattern="([0-9]+)_([^\.]+)\.rb"
    if  [[ $select_migration =~ $pattern ]]; then
        migration_times["${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"]="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

That shortens your code quite considerably and should make it more effective since you are not calling another program.

#### Executing command or listing migrations

If the array does only have one element then you don't need to read the whole pair, you can simply use the value the complete array evaluates to, saving you the lines with reassigning the names. You can also skip the `exit 0` statement because that would overwrite the exit status of your external call. You can tie the listing with an `else` statement to the conditional.
I also used `printf` to give it a nicer look if the length of the names vary `%-10s` has to be adjusted to your needs.

```
if [[ ${#migration_times[@]} == 1 ]]; then
    echo "redo: executing 'bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=${migration_times[*]}'"
    # bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=${migration_times[*]}
else
    echo "redo: be more specific, candidates are:"
    for element in "${!migration_times[@]}"; do
        printf "%-10s : %s\n" $element ${migration_times[$element]}
    done
    exit 1
fi
```

I think you can also easily migrate the changes from your answer to this review.

Comment: Thanks, I also allow 0 arguments. In such case the program will simply list all migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Made the following changes:

- add flags: u, e
- make name program dynamic
- update usage message to reflect that migration_name is optional
- check bash version
- check extra args
- use constants
- refactor migrations dir to a variable
- consistent variable names
- debug the executed command instead of printing it (as recommended in [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050))

The full diff can be found [here](https://github.com/dimidd/redo/commit/e6f0820b4492b88aeb5ce6077f1aedcaec55d1d8).

The new version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -u
set -e
readonly PROG=$(basename $0)

err() {
  echo "$PROG: error: $1"
  echo "$PROG: usage: $PROG [migration_name]"
  exit 1
}

# associative arrays require version >= 4
(( ${BASH_VERSION%%.*} >= 4 )) || err "bash must be at least version 4"
(( $# > 2 )) && err "too many args"
readonly DIR="db/migrate/"
[[ -d $DIR ]] || err "dir $DIR not found"

migs=$(find "$DIR" -name "*.rb" | sed "s#^${DIR}/##")
(( $# == 1 )) && migs=$(echo "$migs" | grep "$1")
declare -A times
for m in $migs; do
  name=$(echo "$m" | sed 's#[0-9]*_\(.*\)\.rb#\1#')
  ver=$(echo "$m" | sed 's#\([0-9]*\)_.*.rb#\1#')
  times["$name"]="$ver"
done

if [[ ${#times[@]} == 1 ]]; then
  name="${!times[@]}"
  ver="${times[$name]}"
  echo "$PROG: executing:"
  set -x
  bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo VERSION="$ver"
  set +x
  exit 0
fi

echo -e "$PROG: be more specific, candidates are:\n"
for t in "${!times[@]}"; do
  echo "$t : ${times[$t]}"
done

set +u
set +e
exit 1
```